# Are we allowed to work on a world language?

Tags: reward-punishment, language

I am thinking on this because it seems God wants us to speak in many languages, to not understand each other. As I know, it is the punishment for the Tower of Babel.

Trying to make world languages (English, Chinese) or constructed languages (Esperanto) common, isn't it an attempt to avoid His punishment?

It seems English or maybe Chinese has a significant chance to elevate to a real world language even in this century.

God's major goal with the punishment - to make the humanity incapable to do global projects on areas which He won't allow for us - seems even now to be nullified because every major industrial / technology / scientific research projects contain enough English speakers to be able to use global resources and global cooperation. As we now can see, this process goes further and further with the decades.

Is it possible, that the punishment is (will be) lifted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple reading of the Tower of Babel is not that it was a punishment but rather that Hashem was not happy about it and so He mixed up their languages so that they can't work together.

The Drush is that there was a punishment and that it was because they had nefarious intentions.

Therefore, if you keep away from their Drush intentions you shouldn't be getting a punishment. If you try to make a single world language you might just not succeed.

What it says is that if the people swell all speak the same language then they will do whatever they please. In today's terms we can understand that although we thought the world will come together in peace efforts, it turns out that nobody understand each other. This way all sides are held in check.

Comment: Or the Sforno -- if the whole world is of one mind and tolerates no dissenting opinions, then if they get off track, they can't produce an Abraham to correct them. So more people speaking one language, sure. More people all forced to think alike -- not okay. You tell me which way the Internet has taken us.